# Woocommerce total sales value from specific coupon

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce

**The issue:**

I need a way to first get all sales made with a specific coupon code. Then get the total revenue from all those sales (and preferably subtracting any returns on those sales. To get the actual revenue value).

**Idea for executing**

I'm using woocommerce 2.6.8 and MySql database for this. My guess is that I would somehow have to first count the number of sales made with a specific coupon with PHP and MySql. Then, for each unique order id with the specific coupon, make a new query for the sum total.

Any suggestions on how the PHP and queries would look like are greatly appreciated  :)

*I should point out that **I'm not looking to get the sum total of the discount from the coupon**. I need to calculate the total value that has been sold with the specific coupon (not the discount).*

OK, so still no working solution thus far. But this is what I believe is the basic structure of it. Getting the total isn't that easy because the coupon isn't directly associated with the order.
I believe that the query would have to be something in the line of this:

**{TBLPRFX}_woocommerce_order_items**

Step 1. GET order_id FOR order_item_name={COUPON_NAME}

Step 2. GET order_item_id FOR order_item_type=line_item WHERE order_id EQUAL {RESULT FROM STEP 1}

| order_item_id | order_item_name | order_item_type | order_id |

| 40971      | {COUPON_NAME}   | coupon        | 001

| 40970      | VAT          | tax          | 001

| 40969      | {PRODUCT_NAME}  | line_item         | 001

--

**{TBLPRFX}_woocommerce_order_itemmeta**

Step 3. SUM meta_value FROM meta_key=_line_tax AND meta_key=_line_total WHERE order_item_id={RESULT FROM STEP 2}

| order_item_id | meta_key      | meta_value |

| 40969      | _line_tax        | {VALUE_TAX}

| 40969      | _line_total      | {VALUE_TOTAL}

| 40969      | _product_id      | {PRODUCT_ID}

--

It's the queries I need help figuring out  :)  Not really sure how to ask for this in MySql and PHP. The idea is to make this a foreach where "order_item_name={COUPON_NAME_VARIABLE}", so I can sum up the total from all sales where that coupon was used (i.e. NOT the coupon discount value).

Comment: Is this a one time query or you're trying to add it into a page as a report? Someone with some knowledge of woocommerce's tables might be able to tell you a simple SQL query to get your result.  This is my google search to start researching https://www.google.com/search?q=woocommerce+sql+query+orders+with+coupon&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 But your SQL query could be something like `SELECT SUM(orderValue) FROM orders WHERE order.coupon='somecoupon'` --- so you wouldn't have to necessarily do any counting or looping and you could just let SQL handle the heavy lifting.

Comment: Adding it as a page for reports could be a future project. Right now I'm fine with just getting the sum on a PHP page  :) I'll take a look at your GSearch and see if I can figure something out... 'till then, please keep your suggestions coming  ;)  Yes, your suggested query is something of what I had in mind, I just don't know how to execute it (and where to find all the columns to look for. Woocommerce isn't very "straight forward" in its SQL structure all the time)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I don't use wordpress or woocommerce, but I deal with databases and generally use 'admin' tools that let me view the SQL tables like excel and then build the SQL query from there --- I don't know if wordpress has something like that or not. Sometimes the tools also are able to create a nice 'web' of all the tables so you can see how they're interconnected.

Comment: So... try phpmyadmin to view wordpress's SQL database and here's woocommerces database descriptions https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description

Comment: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/2.7-Coupon-Data

Comment: Egad ---- https://github.com/bekarice/woocommerce-filter-orders

Comment: Yea, I have it down to woocommerce_order_itemmeta and woocommerce_order_item. What I don't know is how I'm supposed to cross-reference between the two. Cause the woocommerce_order_item hold info on what orders used the specified coupon, while woocommerce_order_itemmeta has the actual value for the sale.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/bekarice/woocommerce-filter-orders/blob/master/woocommerce-filter-orders-by-coupon.php

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Tried it on my dev site. However, this just shows the orders and total number of orders. What I'm looking to get is the total sales value. i.e, if 10 orders used coupon "X" and each order costs $2, the respons I'm looking for would be 20 (total revenue value), not 10 (number of orders)  :)

Comment: Oh boo, from the naming of it "filter orders by coupon" I was hoping it would have been really close to what you were looking for!

Comment: So I've updated my thoughts on this in the post. Anyone who has any suggestions as to how this could be executed?

Comment: Instead of WHERE, it appears you need to JOIN the tables (result 1& 2, then result & 3.) There are many different types of joins though. In some SQL they allow you to do WHERE id in ('1','2','3') but that would not be appropriate with so many rows. (Hopefully someone with more experience can chime in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of testing I came up with a working solution. It's not the sleekest one, but gets the job done.

If any SQL-ninjas see this it would be great if you could suggest any more streamlined queries  :)

After making the first working solution I realized that there are more steps that need to be checked for a more accurate total. Handling refunds, taxes, discounts etc. and also make sure I only get the data from completed orders (since canceled, on-hold, pending etc isn't a sale until it's completed).

So, this is what I ended up with. Like I said, I know it needs some work and could probably be done better. But for now, it works.

- REVISED CODE FOR FUNCTIONS.PHP -

  ```
  // COUPON CHECK
  function couponcheck() {
  global $wpdb;

  $gtl                = 0; // Grand Total
  $total_sales        = 0;
  $cpn                = $_GET['cpn']; // Get coupon name from URL string
  $tblprfx            = '[YOUR_TABLE_PREFIX]'; // Table prefix
  $wpps               = 'posts'; // Look for post_status
  $wppm               = 'postmeta';
  $wcoi               = 'woocommerce_order_items';
  $conversion_value   = 1;
  $base_currency      = '[YOUR_BASE_CURRENCY]';
  $currency;
  $orders_made;

  // Check to make sure there is a couon name in string
  if(isset($cpn) && !empty($cpn)){
      // Query chain
      $init_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT order_id FROM {$tblprfx}{$wcoi} WHERE order_item_name='$cpn'");
      $orders_made = count($init_result);
      foreach($init_result as $ir){
          $r1 = $ir->order_id;
          $completed_result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM {$tblprfx}{$wpps} WHERE post_status='wc-completed' AND ID=$r1" );
          foreach($completed_result as $post_rows) {
              $pr = $post_rows->ID;
              $completed_sales += 1;
              $currency_result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM {$tblprfx}{$wppm} WHERE post_id=$pr AND meta_key='_order_currency'" );
              foreach($currency_result as $cr) {
                  $currency = $cr->meta_value;
                  if($currency === 'EUR'){
                      $currency = 'EUR';
                      $currency_rate = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM {$tblprfx}{$wppm} WHERE post_id=$pr AND meta_key='_woocs_order_rate'" );                           foreach($currency_rate as $rv) {
                          $rate_value = $rv->meta_value;
                          $conversion_value = $rate_value;
                      }
                  }
              }
              $data_result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM {$tblprfx}{$wppm} WHERE post_id=$pr AND meta_key='_order_total'" );
              foreach($data_result as $dr) {
                  $d = $dr->meta_value;
                  if($currency === 'EUR'){
                      $eur += $d;
                      $d = $d/$conversion_value;
                  }else{
                      $[YOUR_BASE_CURRENCY] += $d;
                  }
                  $gtl += $d;
              }
          }
      }
      // Total number of sales
      $refunded_orders = $orders_made-$completed_sales;
      $order_avg = $gtl/$completed_sales;
      echo '<p>Total <strong>completed, non-refunded, sales made (after discounts)</strong> with coupon <strong>' . strtoupper($cpn) . '</strong>: <br />(Number of refunded orders: <strong>' . $refunded_orders . ')</strong></p><h2>' . $completed_sales . '</h2><p>At a total <strong>sales value</strong> of:</p><h2>' . number_format($[YOUR_BASE_CURRENCY],2) . ' [YOUR_BASE_CURRENCY]</h2><h2>&euro;' . number_format($eur,2) . '</h2><p>Adding up to a <strong>sum total</strong> of:</p><h2>' . number_format($gtl,2) . ' [YOUR_BASE_CURRENCY]</h2><p>Creating an average order value of:<br /><strong>' . number_format($order_avg,2) . ' [YOUR_BASE_CURRENCY]</strong>';

  }

  } add_shortcode('coupons', 'couponcheck');
  ```

A small note is that I changed my actual base currency to [YOUR_BASE_CURRENCY]. Comments (constructive ones) are welcome  :)